# Chrome Extension Cleanup on Update/Uninstall

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Is it necessary to cleanup the Chrome extension during an update or uninstall of the extension?

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(func);
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(func);
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(func);
```

As an example I add these listeners at the start of the extension, should I remove them during an extension update occurs? Or Google Chrome handles their removal by itself automatically?